# No FileSystem for scheme:hdfs and Class org.apache.hadoop.DistributedFileSystem not found

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, ant

I want to upload a file to HDFS. I compiled my code using following jars as dependencies:

- hadoop-auth-2.6.1.jar,
- hadoop-common-2.6.1.jar and
- hadoop-hdfs-2.6.1.jar,

My code:

[image]

I compiled it with Ant. But, it gave me this error: `No FileSystem for scheme:hdfs`.

Then I changed the code and compiled again:
[image]

But now I got another error: `Class org.apache.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem not found`.

What's wrong? And what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DistributedFileSystem` is part of `hadoop-core`.

To fix this problem, you need to include `hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar` also (Note: I am using Maven for building):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Overall, I am using following Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, i solved this problem by using httpFS+webHDFS.

Answer (score 0):

While getting Hadoop Filesystem object like below
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(hdfsUrl,configuration);

If you get following error :
"No FileSystem for scheme:hdfs"

You can resolve it by setting following 2 properties on configuration.

```
configuration.set("fs.hdfs.impl","org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem");
configuration.set("fs.file.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem");
```

Now, you may get new error like below :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem not found
```

Hadoop-common.jar uses Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader() and configuration.getClassLoader to load classes.
So, if you set your classLoader by using

```
Thread.currentThread.setContextClassLoader(yourClassLoader); 
configuration.setClassLoader(yourClassLoader);
```

you will be able to load required class from other hadoop jars (e.g. hadoop-hdfs)

Let me know if you need more help. And don't forget to upvote if you find this bit useful.

Comment: You may need to also add `hadoop-hdfs-client` as an artifact in your build file

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, when I compile my Java code into a executable jar and run the compiled jar. Always some error "Not found" (e.g. in your case no FileSystem...), which means some hadoop jar is not included in the compilation.

The solution is add the correct dependencies in the Maven/Gradle or **add (all) the jars**.

In my case, the `hdfs` is from the class `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem` from the `jar`: `hadoop-hdfs-client-3.2.1.jar`.

The relevant `jars` which have been used can be found in the log file (if you successfully run the program and have the log file). In my example is the following:

[image]

You can simply add all the jars (from the installed hadoop folder). They should be in the folder of common/hdfs/ ... under the folder: hadoop 3.2.1/share/hadoop. There are possible other jars which are used but not shown in the log. To be safe, just include all the jars. You can run `hdfs classpath` in the terminal to find the location of all the jars.

Once all the jars have been added, in your java code, you may also need to set the hadoop configuration

```
        Configuration hadoopConfiguration = new Configuration();
        hadoopConfiguration.addResource(new Path(CoreSiteXMLStr));
        hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.hdfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem");
```

[image]